# Как перевести Sin(2a) в радианы?

Tags: c#

Как перевести Sin(2a) в радианы не зная а.
Суть задания "Реализуйте функцию расчета угла прицеливания, в зависимости от начальной скорости снаряда и дальности до цели. Если решения не существует, метод должен возвращать double.NaN."

```
{
    public static class AngryBirdsTask
    {
        // Ниже — это XML документация, её использует ваша среда разработки, 
        // чтобы показывать подсказки по использованию методов. 
        // Но писать её естественно не обязательно.
        /// <param name="v">Начальная скорость</param>
        /// <param name="distance">Расстояние до цели</param>
        /// <returns>Угол прицеливания в радианах от 0 до Pi/2</returns>
        public static double FindSightAngle(double v, double distance)
        {
            const double g = 9.8;
            double sin2a;
            sin2a = (g * distance) / Math.Sqrt(v);
            Console.WriteLine(sin2a);
            return Math.PI / 4;
        }
    }
}
```

15-18 строчку добавил от себя

Comment: значение синуса вычисляется в радианах и так

Comment: при чем тут C#? что именно не получается? покажите код и суть задачи, которую пытаетесь решить.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: _15-18 строчку добавил от себя_ - здесь не нумеруются строчки

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна функция арксинус. В шарпе это `Math.Asin`

Comment: Ответ помог?...